# inavalid int error while passing the value to spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my project i am using spinner with numeric values 50,100. i am passing the values to the spinner using strings.xml. how can i get this spinner value as a integer. i am using below code but it gives the invalid int error.
here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reload_newvalue);

        SpnTopupValue=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        btnBUY=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuy);

        Thelper=new TransactionDBAdapter(this);
        i=new Intent(this,ReloadHistory.class);

        ArrayAdapter Tadapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Topupvalue, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        SpnTopupValue.setAdapter(Tadapter);     

        btnBUY.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){    
                @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Transaction tran=new Transaction();                 
                int TopupValue =Integer.parseInt(SpnTopupValue.getContext().toString());            

                tran.setTran_cardno(RegCardNo);
                tran.setTran_cardname(RegcardName);          
                tran.setTran_topupval(TopupValue);   
                Thelper.open();         
                Thelper.ReloadNewCard(tran);           
                startActivity(i);   
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Strings array

```
<array name="Topupvalue">
    <item>50</item>
    <item>100</item>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing,

```
int TopupValue =Integer.parseInt(SpnTopupValue.getContext().toString());
```

to,

```
int TopupValue =Integer.parseInt(SpnTopupValue.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
```

Hope it helps!